# Are questions that require installing an app on topic on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, spam

I just read this [question post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39069401/no-device-is-compatible-for-my-android-game) which has specific issue regarding applications visibility on certain android device. The app is in alpha testing mode and in order to answer these kind of questions user is required to:

- become alpha tester of app.
- download/install the app on android.

I just have one question that how can someone tell whether it is a real problem or just a spam?

(NB: I am not calling the OP spam in anyway and am willing to install the app if that helps in solving problem)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it ***in the question itself***. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

There's a close-vote reason specifically for questions like these.

Problems should be reproducible from the question itself, without requiring any external resources.

As soon as the problem is fixed, this specific question loses all it's value.

Comment: Well. the question is clearly not related to programming. So where can one ask these kind of questions? I don't want to cause meta affect for OP (Same thing happened to me, [users started down-voting my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742312/add-texture-to-unlit-transparent-color-shader) )

Comment: That exact question is off-topic anywhere on the SE network, actually.